# what is the fastest way to replace multiple words in a very long string simultaneously

Tags: qt, str-replace

Suppose I have a string which contains more than 10,000 words, for example, it is the contents of the famous fiction "The old man and Sea"

and a dictionary which have 1,000 words pairs,for example,

```
before，after
--------------
fish , net
black, white
good, bad
....
....
round,rect
```

so what I want to do is ,according to the dictionary ,replace all 'fish' in   the string with 'net', 'black' with 'white' ....

the simplest and intuitive algorithm is :

```
foreach(line, dict)
   str.replace(line.before,line.after)
```

but it was so inefficiency.

one improvement I can think of is to 
separate the string to multiple small string, then 
use multithread to handle each smallstring respectively ,then combine the result.

is there any other ideas?

btw, I am using QT

Comment: I wouldn't use replace at all for your purposes as it has no concept of words, only character sequences.  So in your example the word "rounded" would become "rected", instead of being left alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a better idea to have a vector of 10k words, not a string of characters.

Just like this:

```
QVector<QString> myLongString;
```

Your dictionary can be implemented as a hash table:

```
QHash<QString, QString> dict;
```

This will provide constant access time to your dictionary words:

```
QString replaceWith = dict.value("fish") // replaceWith == "net"
```

Then you can iterate through your vector and replace words:

```
for (int i=0; i < myLongString.size(); ++i)
{
    QString word = myLongString[i];
    if dict.contains(word)
    {
        myLongString[i] = dict.value(word);
    }
}
```